# Highest weight category and weight structures

Tags: rt.representation-theory, triangulated-categories, weights

In various branches of representation theory, there is a notion of [highest weight category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highest-weight_category).

On the other hand there is a notion of weight structure on a triangulated category $C$ (introduced by Bondarko; also known as a co-t-structure as introduced by Pauksztello, see e.g. [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1011.3507v4)). This concept is in a way dual to a t-structure in the sense that a weight structure is a datum $(C^{w \le 0}, C^{w \ge 1})$ of two full subcategories of $C$ such that any object $X \in C$ has a weight truncation triangle $X^{\le 0} \to X \to X^{\ge 1}$ (with the outer terms in the respective subcategories), 
$$Hom(C^{w \le 0}, C^{w \ge 1}) = 0,$$
and
$$C^{w \le 0}[-1] \subset C^{w \le 0}$$ 
(the latter is unlike for a t-structure, where the axioms demand $C^{t \le 0}[+1] \subset C^{t \le 0}$.) Thus, in a nutshell, while t-structures are supposed to prevent negative Ext's, weight structures are supposed to prevent positive Ext's.

This motivates the following question: are highest weight categories related (in the literature) to this notion of weight structure? (E.g., given such a category $A$, what about a weight structure on the derived category $D(A)$ and conversely?)